# How to reload html resources in wicket

Tags: wicket

Wicket reload html resources

I would like to have URL which reload all my application resources

```
//localhost:8080/myApp/reloadWicket
```

I know i can achieve it by using :

```
 getResourceSettings().setResourcePollFrequency()
```

How can i do it with simple filter/URL

my app is wicket and spring therefore i would like to ignore cases with my spring components , the only thing I would like is to refresh all the ***.html** resourcres fevery time a certin link is being called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Application.get().getMarkupFactory().getMarkupCache().clear()
```

Comment: Notice in 6.x Application.get().getMarkupSettings().getMarkupFactory().getMarkupCache().clear();